# c How to insert a element in a sublist

Tags: c

I have a list of products of several categories in the file "Magazzino.txt" here below:

```
A451XX (codice prodotto)
CAT001 (codice categoria)
PASTA CONF. 1KG
100
99.0
A451XY (codice prodotto)
CAT002 (codice categoria)
MAGLIA LANA
25
6.70
A452XX (codice prodotto)
CAT001 (codice categoria)
SUGO
33
9.99
```

First I have to read the file and copy all products in a list with the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char codP[C];
    char codC[C];
    char descr[D];
    int num;
    float costo;
} tipoBaseLista;

typedef struct nodoLista{
    tipoBaseLista info;
    struct nodoLista *next;
}prodotto;

typedef prodotto *listaP;
```

I need to copy this list of products in a list of categories such that each category has a sublist with all product that belong to the specific category. The structure of this list of list is:

```
typedef struct nodoCat{
    char codC[C];
    struct nodoCat *next;
    listaP nodoP; //puntatore al sottonodo prodotto
}categoria;

typedef categoria *listaC;
```

This is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define C 8
#define D 64

typedef struct {
    char codP[C];
    char codC[C];
    char descr[D];
    int num;
    float costo;
} tipoBaseLista;

typedef struct nodoLista{
    tipoBaseLista info;
    struct nodoLista *next;
}prodotto;

typedef prodotto *listaP;

typedef struct nodoCat{
    char codC[C];
    struct nodoCat *next;
    listaP nodoP; 
}categoria;

typedef categoria *listaC;

int carica_lista(char fName[], listaP *l);
void inserimentoProd(listaP *l, tipoBaseLista p);
listaC trovaCategoria(listaC lc, char categoria[]);
void inserimentoSottolista(listaC lc, tipoBaseLista p, listaP *l);

int main() {
    char filename[] = "Magazzino.txt";
    listaP lista = NULL;
    listaC listaCat = NULL;
    tipoBaseLista prodotto;

    printf("\nNumero prodotti caricati: %d\n", carica_lista(filename, &lista));

    if(lista == NULL){
        printf("\nLa lista dei prodotti è vuota!\n");
    }

    while(lista != NULL){
        prodotto = lista->info;
        if(listaCat == NULL){
            listaCat = malloc(sizeof(categoria));
            strcpy(listaCat->codC, prodotto.codC);
            listaCat->next = NULL;
            inserimentoSottolista(listaCat, prodotto, &lista);
        }
        else{
            listaCat = trovaCategoria(listaCat, prodotto.codC);
        if(listaCat != NULL){
                inserimentoSottolista(listaCat, prodotto, &lista);
        }
            else{
                listaCat = listaCat->next;
                inserimentoSottolista(listaCat, prodotto, &lista);
            }

        }

        lista = lista->next;
    }       
    return 0;
    system("PAUSE");
}

//read from file
int carica_lista(char fName[], listaP *l) {
    tipoBaseLista prodotto;
    int n = 0;
    char buf[D] = {0};
    char scarto[30];
    FILE *f; 
    f = fopen(fName, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Non e' possibile aprire il file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!feof(f)) {
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f);
        sscanf(buf, "%s%s", prodotto.codP, scarto);
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f);
        sscanf(buf, "%s%s", prodotto.codC, scarto);
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f);
        strcpy(prodotto.descr, buf);
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f);
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &prodotto.num);
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f);
        sscanf(buf, "%f", &prodotto.costo);

        inserimentoProd(l, prodotto);
        n++;
    }

        fclose(f);
        return n;
        system("PAUSE");
}

//to insert product in the list
void inserimentoProd(listaP *l, tipoBaseLista p){
    listaP pCorrente = NULL; 
    listaP pNodo; 
    listaP pPrec;
    pNodo = malloc(sizeof(prodotto));
    pNodo->info = p;
    pNodo->next = NULL;
    if (*l == NULL){
        *l = pNodo;
    }

    else if(strcmp(p.codP, (*l)->info.codP) < 0){
        pNodo->next = *l;
        *l = pNodo;
        (*l)->next = pNodo;
    }

    else{
        pCorrente = *l; 
        while (pCorrente->next != NULL && strcmp(p.codP, pCorrente->info.codP) > 0){
            pPrec = pCorrente;
            pCorrente = pCorrente->next;
        }

        if(strcmp(p.codP, pCorrente->info.codP) < 0){
            pNodo->next = pCorrente;
            pPrec->next = pNodo;
        }
        else if(pCorrente->next == NULL) {
            pCorrente->next = pNodo;
        }
    }
}


//To find the category node under which we insert the sublist
listaC trovaCategoria(listaC lc, char categoria[]){
    listaC pCorrente = lc;
    while(pCorrente != NULL){
        if(strcmp(pCorrente->codC, categoria) == 0){
            printf("\nCategoria già presente.\n");
            return pCorrente;
        }
        pCorrente = pCorrente->next;
    }
    return(NULL);
}

//to insert the product in the head of sublist
void inserimentoSottolista(listaC lc, tipoBaseLista p, listaP *l){
printf("\nInserimento nella sottolista\n");
    listaP prodotto = malloc(sizeof(struct nodoLista));
    prodotto->info = p;
    prodotto->next = *l;
    *l = prodotto;
    lc->nodoP = prodotto;
    printf("\nInserimento effettuato\n");
}
```

There must be some problem in the "inserimentoSottolista" that cause the crash of the program. What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here, inside inserimentoSottolista:

```
listaP prodotto = malloc(sizeof(prodotto));
```

You need `sizeof(prodotto)` to be the size of the struct that was declared earlier, i.e. `sizeof(struct nodoLista)`.  But you have used the same name for the name of the variable being initialized.  In this case, the `prodotto` in `sizeof(prodotto)` isn't the struct, but is the variable.  So `sizeof(prodotto)` ends up being the same as `sizeof(listaP)`, which is just the size of a pointer.  It's too small, so you aren't allocating enough memory.

You can fix it by changing the variable name so that it doesn't mask the type name, or by using `sizeof(struct nodoLista)`.

Comment: Thank you. I had not realised of this mistake. I correct it but now a infinite loop occur because "lista" point always at the head of the list of product. I think because of this 2 following lines in "inserimentoSottolista": prodotto->next = *l; and *l = prodotto; How can I avoid this?

Comment: I don't think you provided enough information to determine what's causing your loop.  If you're passing `&lista` for `l`, then `*l = prodotto;` should update `lista` in the caller.  But the code you posted doesn't seem like it's doing anything - it looks like `lista` starts as `NULL`, the loop is skipped, and it exits.  What are you actually running?

Comment: I also add the functions that fill the first list reading from a file. The reading from the file and the list loading work already.